# Rounded Corner for FLTK-Window

Tags: fltk

Many modern applications feature rounded corners for their windows, see Photoshop, which has rounded corners in the top left and right.

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to implement rounded corners in FLTK. Right now, when I set my window's frame to rounded corners, the background color of my app (black) still shows through:

[image]

Any work arounds for this?

Comment: Which OS are you using? On Mac I get rounded corners by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [shape](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#aeb3ffb4925bd90950de419f962bcf7f6) member function may help in achieving what you are searching for. The below image is the window created by the example code you can find in `example/shapedwindow.cxx`:

[image: shapedwindow.cxx without upper bar]

You see that you can get any shape you want. The drawback is that there is not the upper bar with window's name and `close`, `iconize` and `enlarge` buttons. These can be made visible by adding `win->border(1);` just before `win->show();` in the code, but the result is not quite appealing.

[image: shapedwindow.cxx with upper bar]